# VBA: Line Input #, next file not showing new data

Tags: excel, vba, csv, input, line

I'm reading multiple csv files into excel for some number crunching. The file reads appear to work with each excel column having the csv file name inserted for confirmation. Odd thing. Each csv file name is correctly inserted into the sheet, but the data is all the same as the first file.

Is there a way to flush / reset ..... something, so the next read file data actually is the next file?

Excel VBA code snippet:

```
Public Const sRawFilePath As String = "\\server1\Sample.RAW.Files\"
----------------
Sub ImportCSV()
Dim sFullFilePath, sFile As String
fFIle = FreeFile()

sFile = Dir(sRawFilePath & "*.csv")
sFullFilePath = sRawFilePath & sFile

While sFile <> ""
    Open sFullFilePath For Input As fFIle 
        While Not EOF(fFIle)  
            Line Input #fFIle, sLine
            ""
            "take the sLine string and separate the comma delimited values for insertion into columns "
            "This part works fine"
            ""
        Wend
    Close fFIle 
sFile = Dir()
Wend
End Sub
```

Stepping through the code I can confirm the next file is in the queue, but the read data is not representing the next file, just the first file, ... and always the first file even though 20 more files are read.

PS - This forum has been an amazing resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you define `sFullFilePath` which locks in the file that you're opening.  So even though you're successfully looping through the files with `Dir`, you will only open the first one because you locked it in.  Don't use that variable at all:

```
'Change this line
Open sFullFilePath For Input As fFIle

'To be this instead
Open sRawFilePath & sFile For Input As fFIle
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found the mistake where the 'sFullFilePath = sRawFilePath & sFile' was not being redefined within the loop. My bad...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than executing `Dir(sRawFilePath & "*.csv")` in every call, you should just execute `Dir` in subsequent calls. The error causes you to re-read the first file again and again.